# Group Theory Proof and Answer

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(G,*)$ be a group such that for any $a,b \in G$, we have
$$(a*b)^{71}=a^{71} * b^{71}\\
 (a*b)^{72}=a^{72} * b^{72}\\
 (a*b)^{73}=a^{73} * b^{73}
$$ Prove that G is Abelian Group. 
Note-'*star' is any binary operator, it may be '+' or '-' or '*'(multipication) or '/'.
 We have to proove a*b = b*a

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please do not dump your exercises on us. If you tell us what you've tried and where you got stuck then you're likely to get useful answers.

Comment: Sir can i get the answer of my question..

Answer (score 1):

$$a^{73}b^{73}=ab(ab)^{72}=aba^{72}b^{72}.$$
Thus,
$$a^{72}b=ba^{72}$$ or
$$a^{72}=ba^{72}b^{-1}.$$
By the same way we obtain:
$$a^{71}=ba^{71}b^{-1}.$$
Hence, $$aba^{71}b^{-1}=ba^{72}b^{-1}$$ or
$$ab=ba.$$

Comment: Sir please tell me for any binary operator.

Answer (score 1):

We have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x=(ab)^n= a^n b^n \\
y=(ab)^{n+1} =a^{n+1} b^{n+1} \\
(ab)^{n+2}= a^{n+2} b^{n+2}
\end{eqnarray*}
From the first & second equations we have $bx=xb$, ($abx=(ab)^{n+1}=a^{n+1}b^{n+1}=a(a^nb^n)b=axb$ )

Similarly form the second & third equations we have $by=yb$, we also have $y=abx$ so ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
abxb= yb= by =babx =baxb
\end{eqnarray*}
Now left multiply this by $ b^{-1} x^{-1}$ and we have $ab=ba$.

Comment: Sir please tell me for any binary operator.

Comment: Mr. Kumar,  the answer provided here is as general as it can be.  The statement is not valid for an arbitrary binary operation on a set, but only for the binary operation in a group, which must satisfy the group axioms.  The operation denoted here by juxtaposition $(a, b) \mapsto ab$ represents the multiplication in any group:  it could be multiplication of invertible matrices, addition of vectors in  a vector space, composition of symmetries, etc.  It cannot be subtraction or division of numbers, for example,  since these operations are not associative.